# phpunit can't find doctrine annotations

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony

i'm working in a sylius project and i had some functional tests working. It happens sylius has switched to symfony 3.2 and lot of my tests are not working anymore after this.

whenever i try to run the tests i get errors like

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in class ...\Entity\Block does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

My phpunit.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true"
     bootstrap="var/bootstrap.php.cache">
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./app" />
</php>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./src/AppBundle/Tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

and finally, my test has this kind of setup

```
abstract class BaseTestCase extends KernelTestCase {
...
protected function setUp()
{
    static::bootKernel();
}
}
```

Any idea on what could be wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 1):

found the fix. i decided to take a look to the [phpunit.xml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.2.0/phpunit.xml.dist) in the sf standard repo and changed my "boostrap" option to be "app/autoload.php" instead. this fixes that kind of errors i was getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true"
     bootstrap="app/autoload.php">
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./app" />
</php>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./src/AppBundle/Tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```